# Running Cypress Test: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '__/'?

Tags: angular, testing, redirect, cypress, forgerock

When running a cpress test in my angular application, I chose Edge and chose any spec-File:
[image]
 
Then a separate Edge-Window (not Cypress) opens:

[image]

Now im authenticated, but the redirection doesn't work:
[image]

When I refresh the page, I get correct redirected to localhost:4200/search.
I want the test to be automatic, so I dont want to refresh the page when authenticated.
Do you know, what I did wrong?

Comment: Hi, have you found a work around this?

Comment: Figured that this is caused my lazily loaded modules.